# piecewise function with 3d plot

Tags: python, numpy, piecewise

I am having trouble getting `np.piecewise` to work for multiple dimensional plotting due to broadcast errors.

Does anyone have any manner to get around this?

Here is what I have in a simplified executable script:

```
import numpy as np
from pylab import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d, Axes3D 

num_steps = 100
x_arr = np.linspace(0,100, num_steps)
y_arr = np.linspace(0,20, num_steps)

def zfunc(x, y):
    return np.piecewise(x, [x>=500, x<500], [x, -x])

x,y = np.meshgrid(x_arr, y_arr)
z =zfunc(x,y)

fig=plt.figure()
ax=fig.subplot(1,1,1,projection='3d')
p = x.plot_surface(x,y,z,rstride=1,cstride=1,cmap=cm.coolwarm,linewidth=0,antialiased=False)
plt.show()
```

Which gives the error:

```
 return np.piecewise(x, [x>=500, x<500], [x, -x])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py", line 716, in piecewise
    y[condlist[k]] = item
ValueError: array is not broadcastable to correct shape
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking a look at the docstring of the function you're using is usually a good idea. I found this solution there.

```
np.piecewise(x, [x>=500, x<500], [lambda x: x, lambda x: -x])
```

> funclist : list of callables, f(x,*args,**kw), or scalars
>       Each function is evaluated over `x` wherever its corresponding
>       condition is True.  It should take an array as input and give an array
>       or a scalar value as output.  If, instead of a callable,
>       a scalar is provided then a constant function (`lambda x: scalar`) is
>       assumed.

Comment: Thank you much! I thought it was an issue dealing with `np.meshgrid` or something, but I should have looked into this more. Thank you for the help it works great